# nouns and prepositions inside infinitives

Tags: prepositions, nouns, infinitives

Two phrases from [English-Russian dictionary of mechanical engineering and automation](https://slovar-vocab.com/english-russian/manufacturing-automation-dictionary/harden-3211320.html):

> *to face harden*
>
> *to through harden*

That is we have the noun "*face*" and the preposition "*through*" inside the infinitive "*to harden*".

Some examples I could find in the internet:

> [barfatigueblog.org](https://barfatigueblog.org/2015/09/08/comparison-of-through-induction-hardening-with-conventional-hardening/):
> *Two methods are often used **to through harden** and low alloy steels*.
>
> [kundoc.com](https://kundoc.com/pdf-26-surface-induction-hardening-.html):
> *In doing this it is possible **to through harden** the gear part down to the tooth root (in the same way as the classical case hardening) or to harden the outer surface at either a uniform or irregular depth from the surface*.
>
> [developmentbookshelf.com](https://www.developmentbookshelf.com/doi/abs/10.3362/0262-8104.1982.004?journalCode=wl):
> *The cutting teeth are cut from mild steel water pipe, and untreated, although it would be a simple matter **to face harden** the cutting points for abrasive conditions*.

What is the rule of using prepositions and nouns inside infinitives?

Thanks!

Comment: *through harden* sounds like a forced translation of Ger *durchhärten*, with *durch* "done" as in "thoroughly cooked", "are you through?", "is it through". Compounds like *sunbath* are never split, technical terms are understood as compounds, to avoid confusion with *to harden through*.

Comment: The "to"s of your examples are not prepositions; rather, they form marked infinitives with the following verbs "through harden" and "face harden".  The verbs are compounds.

Comment: Note that "face harden" and "through harden" are phrasal verbs. You do not treat them as two POSs.

Comment: @GregLee By prepositions, the OP means *face* and *through*, not *to*.

Comment: @Kris, Well, those aren't prepositions, either.  They are the first elements of compound verbs.  "face harden" and "through harden" are not "phrasal verbs" -- they're just verbs.